# Private runtimeConfig (API token) can't be used in client-side NUXT 3 universal rendering

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am using composables to set default headers for useFetch() like this:

```
// ~/composables/useMyFetch.js
export const useMyFetch = (request, opts) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();

  return useFetch(request, {
    baseURL: config.public.BASE_URL,
    headers: {
      "X-API-KEY": useRuntimeConfig().API_TOKEN,
    },
  });
};
```

And my nuxt.config.js file includes

```
runtimeConfig: {
  API_TOKEN: process.env.API_TOKEN,
  public: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  },
},
```

This useMyFetch() composable works fine on the first load of the page. But after navigating to other pages, it doesn't work (403). I found that reason for this is, the API_TOKEN that is not inside public runtimeConfig is not accessible on the client-side (after navigating to other pages).

Is there any other better way to set default headers for useFetch()? Or any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me be clear, I'm not sure what your end goal is. If you need to keep API_TOKEN away from the client, then create a proxy on the server, where you will have the access to it. If you can expose the api key, then make it public. `useFetch` isn't designed for accessing server parameters, it's just for being able to fetch data on the client and server in the same fashion.

Here is how to setup a proxy to your service.
Create a file in server/api/otherService/[...path.ts]

```
const config = useRuntimeConfig()

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    return proxyRequest(
        event,
        `${config.public.BASE_URL}/${event.context.params!.path}`,
        { headers: { "X-API-KEY": config.API_TOKEN } }
    )
})
```

Then you can use `useFetch` without knowing the api key or even the base path.

```
const data = useFetch("/api/otherService/my-call")
```

Note however, that you are still exposing access to some other api by doing so. Basically, your-url/api/otherService will allow any malicious user to access that other service with your api key, even though they won't have the key. As such, I would recommend to create some kind of protection against that, although, I don't know what your goals are.

Comment: Thank You for your quick response. I tried this method but it doesn't work, but I dont know why. Instead of proxyRequest I used this below:
  return await $fetch(event.context.params!._, {
    baseURL: config.public.BASE_URL,
    headers: {
      "X-API-KEY": config.API_TOKEN,
    },
  });

Anyway Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I thought you could just use appendHeader. It seems, you need to pass headers to proxy request. I updated my answer.